# How can I make this boolean variable change from False to True?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a boolean private field variable on my Main Activity that is set to False:

```
private boolean accountCreated = false;
```

When the acccount is created, I set it to true:

```
        createAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = nameInput.getText().toString();
            username = usernameInput.getText().toString();
            age = Integer.parseInt(ageInput.getText().toString());
            saveData();
            openMainMenuActivity();
            accountCreated = true;
        }
    });
```

but the boolean value isn't changing from false to true. The code shown above is located inside the ***MainActivity.java*** class and inside a public void method. I want this boolean value to change because if false the user can't play, if true the user will be able to play.

Comment: Can you provide more code? It is not clear what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `openMainMenuActivity();` was resetting the value of the **boolean**. Instead of using `openMainMenuActivity();` I opted to make a popup stating that the account was created successfully and simply dismissing the popup when the user presses **X**, hence going back to the `openMainMenuActivity();` and the **boolean** value didn't reset. That made it work for me. Thanks to everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I  guess you try to continue your game in `openMainMenuActivity()` method so try to move the `accountCreated = true;` before `openMainMenuActivity();`

Otherwise it's hard to tell without providing more of your code

Comment: I tried that before posting, thanks, but it didn't work. @Zain

Answer (score 0):

`openMainMenuActivity()` method should work in that way

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("isAccountCreated", accountCreated);
            startActivity(i);
```

And in `OtherActivity`'s simply should look like this

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean aDifferentAccountCreatedBoolean;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        aDifferentAccountCreatedBoolean = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isAccountCreated", false);
        //Do stuff


    }
```

}